# Proof of Liouville's Principle.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, indefinite-integrals, elementary-functions

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LiouvillesPrinciple.html

"Algorithms for Computer Algebra" by Geddes. Contains a proof in chapter "12.4" Liouville's Principle. But I can't find the pdf for free.

Can anyone find or provide a demonstration please.

Answer (score 2):

See *An Invitation to Integration in Finite Terms*, by Elena Anne Marchisotto and Gholam-Ali Zakeri (*The College Mathematics Journal*, **25**, no. 4 (Sep., 1994), pp. 295–308). You will find it [here](http://www.rangevoting.org/MarchisottoZint.pdf). The theorem that you are interested in is what they call “Liouville's 1834 theorem”.